# jq streaming of large json files to get only objects whose properties have a specific value

Tags: json, mapreduce, jq

I have some rather large json files (~500mb - 4gb compressed) for which I cannot load into memory for manipulation. So I am using the `--stream` option with jq.

For example my json might look like this - only bigger:

```
[{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters": {
    "batter": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "type": "Regular"
    }, {
      "id": "1002",
      "type": "Chocolate"
    }, {
      "id": "1003",
      "type": "Blueberry"
    }, {
      "id": "1004",
      "type": "Devil's Food"
    }]
  },
  "topping": [{
    "id": "5001",
    "type": "None"
  }, {
    "id": "5002",
    "type": "Glazed"
  }, {
    "id": "5005",
    "type": "Sugar"
  }, {
    "id": "5007",
    "type": "Powdered Sugar"
  }, {
    "id": "5006",
    "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
  }, {
    "id": "5003",
    "type": "Chocolate"
  }, {
    "id": "5004",
    "type": "Maple"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "0002",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Raised",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters": {
    "batter": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "type": "Regular"
    }]
  },
  "topping": [{
    "id": "5001",
    "type": "None"
  }, {
    "id": "5002",
    "type": "Glazed"
  }, {
    "id": "5005",
    "type": "Sugar"
  }, {
    "id": "5003",
    "type": "Chocolate"
  }, {
    "id": "5004",
    "type": "Maple"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "0003",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Old Fashioned",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters": {
    "batter": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "type": "Regular"
    }, {
      "id": "1002",
      "type": "Chocolate"
    }]
  },
  "topping": [{
    "id": "5001",
    "type": "None"
  }, {
    "id": "5002",
    "type": "Glazed"
  }, {
    "id": "5003",
    "type": "Chocolate"
  }, {
    "id": "5004",
    "type": "Maple"
  }]
}]
```

If this were the type of file I could hold in memory, and I wanted to select objects that only have batter type "Chocolate", I could use:

`cat sample.json | jq '.[] | select(.batters.batter[].type == "Chocolate")'`

And I would only get back the full objects with ids `"0001"` and `"0003"`

But with streaming I know it's different.

I am reading through the jq documentation on streaming [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) and [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser), but I am still quite confused as the examples don't really demonstrate real world problems with json.

Namely, Is it even possible to select whole objects after streaming through their paths and identifying a notable event, or in this case a property value that matches a certain string?

I know that I can use:

`cat sample.json | jq --stream 'select(.[0][1] == "batters" and .[0][2] == "batter" and .[0][4] == "type") | .[1]'`

to give me all of the batter types. But is there a way to say: "If it's Chocolate, grab the object this leaf is a part of"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command:

```
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' array_of_objects.json | 
  jq 'select(.batters.batter[].type == "Chocolate") | .id'
```

Output:

```
"0001"
"0003"
```

The first invocation of jq converts the array of objects into a stream of objects.  The second is based on your invocation and can be tailored further to your needs.

Of course the two invocations can (and probably should) be combined into one, but you might want to use the first invocation to save the big file as a file containing the stream of objects.

By the way, it would probably be better to use the following `select`:

```
select( any(.batters.batter[]; .type == "Chocolate") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.  Start with a streaming filter `filter1.jq` that extracts the record number and the minimum set of attributes you need to process.  E.g.

```
  select(length==2)
| . as [$p, $v]
| {r:$p[0]}
| if   $p[1] == "id"                           then .id   = $v
  elif $p[1] == "batters" and $p[-1] == "type" then .type = $v
  else  empty
  end
```

Running this with

```
jq -M -c --stream -f filter1.jq bigdata.json
```

produces values like

```
{"r":0,"id":"0001"}
{"r":0,"type":"Regular"}
{"r":0,"type":"Chocolate"}
{"r":0,"type":"Blueberry"}
{"r":0,"type":"Devil's Food"}
{"r":1,"id":"0002"}
{"r":1,"type":"Regular"}
{"r":2,"id":"0003"}
{"r":2,"type":"Regular"}
{"r":2,"type":"Chocolate"}
```

now pipe this into a second filter `filter2.jq` which does the processing you want on those attributes for each record

```
foreach .[] as $i (
     {c: null, r:null, id:null, type:null}

   ; .c = $i
   | if .r != .c.r then .id=null | .type=null | .r=.c.r else . end   # control break
   | .id   = if .c.id == null   then .id   else .c.id   end
   | .type = if .c.type == null then .type else .c.type end

   ; if ([.id, .type] | contains([null])) then empty else . end
)
| select(.type == "Chocolate").id
```

with a command like

```
jq -M -c --stream -f filter1.jq bigdata.json | jq -M -s -r -f filter2.jq
```

to produce

```
0001
0003
```

`filter1.jq` and `filter2.jq` do a little more than what you need for this specific problem but they can be generalized easily.